# Finding the Minor Matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I have a Matrix class that has the following method

```
    private Matrix matrixMinors()
    {
    double[][] matrixM = new double[matrix.length][matrix.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < matrixM.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < matrixM.length; j++)
        {
            double[][] newone = new double[matrixM.length - 1][matrixM.length - 1];
            for(int k = 0; k < newone.length; k++)
                for(int h = 0; h < newone[0].length; h++)
                    if(k == i)
                        ;
                    else if(h == j)
                        ;
                    else
                        newone[k][h] = matrix[k][h];
            test(newone, "little matrix"); //this just prints the matrix for debugging purposes
            matrixM[i][j] = determinant(newone, newone.length);
        }
    test(matrixM, "minor matrix"); //this just prints the matrix for debugging purposes
    return new Matrix(matrixM);
}
```

When printed the minor matrix has all zeros, any suggestions as to how to fix this.

Update:

My determinant method keeps printing only zeros, but I'm not sure if that's just because the data I'm giving it makes a zero determinant or my code is faulty.

```
    private double determinant(double[][] mat, int size)
    {
    double det = 0;
    if(size == 1)
        det = mat[0][0];
    else if (size == 2)
        det = mat[0][0] * mat[1][1] - mat[1][0] * mat[0][1];
    else
    {
        for(int j1 = 0; j1 < size; j1++)
        {
            double[][] m = new double[size-1][];
            for(int k = 0; k < (size-1); k++)
                m[k] = new double[size-1];
            for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                int j2 = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    if(j == j1)
                        continue;
                    m[i-1][j2] = mat[i][j];
                    j2++;
                }
            }
            det += Math.pow(-1.0, 1.0 + j1 + 1.0) * mat[0][j1] * determinant(m, size - 1);
        }
    }
    return det;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first advice would be to replace the ugly if-else:

This one:

```
if(k == i)
;
else if(h == j)
;
else
newone[k][h] = matrix[k][h];
```

With:

```
if(k!=i && h!=j) {
  System.out.println("test: "+matrix[k][h]);//to see if it enters here
  newone[k][h] = matrix[k][h];
}
```

If the test is not printed, then the logic is wrong.

My second advice:
Write a UnitTest for your determinant method or at least check what it returns (a System.out could help). If it always returns 0, then the minor matrix is, of course, all zeros.

Edit:
You do not need to pass the size to determinant. You can simply use:

```
private double determinant(double[][] mat)
{
  int size = mat.length;
```

I tested that method with a few matixes like this:

```
final double[][] mat = new double[][] { { 1, 0, 1 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 2, 0, 1 } };
final double det = determinant(mat, 3);
System.out.println("det: " + det);
```

The result was as expected.

Since newone is not as expected, here a Test class you can use:

```
public class TestMatrix
{

    private static final double delta   = 0.0001;

    @Test
    public void testDeterminant()
    {
        final double[][] mat = new double[][] { { 1.5, 2.7, 3.8 }, { -4.1, 5.4, -6.6 }, { 7.1, 8000, 9000 } };
        final double det = Matrix.determinant(mat, 3);
        assertEquals(126817.786, det, delta);
    }

    // TODO add other tests!

    @Test
    public void testNewOne() throws Exception
    {
        final double[][] matrix = { { 3, 0, 2 }, { 2, 0, -2 }, { 0, 1, 1 } };
        final double[][] newOne = Matrix.newOne(matrix, 0, 0);
        assertMatrix(new double[][] { { 0, -2 }, { 1, 1 } }, newOne);
    }

    private void assertMatrix(final double[][] ds, final double[][] newOne)
    {
        assertEquals(ds.length, newOne.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.length; i++)
        {
            assertEquals(ds[i].length, newOne[i].length);
            for (int j = 0; j < ds[i].length; j++)
            {
                assertEquals(ds[i][j], newOne[i][j], delta);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a newOne method like this:

```
public static double[][] newOne(final double[][] matrix, final int i, final int j)
    {
        final double[][] newone = new double[matrix.length - 1][matrix.length - 1];
        for(int k = 0; k < newone.length; k++)
        {
            for(int h = 0; h < newone[0].length; h++)
                if (k != i && h != j)
                {
                    newone[k][h] = matrix[k][h];
                }
        }
        return newone;
    }
```

Your matrixMinor would then be:

```
//...
for(int i = 0; i < matrixM.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < matrixM.length; j++)
    {
        double[][] newone = newOne(matrixM, i, j);
        test(newone, "little matrix");
        matrixM[i][j]=determinant(newone, newone.length);
    }
//...
```

Then just change the method newOne until the UnitTest pass (a few more Tests wouldn't hurt, I just wrote one to show you how it can be done).

Comment: I replaced my if else but it is still printing the same results.

Comment: test is printing, but not 4 times like it should, usually only once or twice. See my updated question for my determinant

Comment: newone is not as expected simply running it as is with                         matrix double[][] matrix = {{3, 0, 2}, {2, 0, -2}, {0, 1, 1}}; newone the first iteration should be {{0, -2},{1, 1}}. however it just appears as zeros

Comment: There you go. With that you should be able to solve your problem!